# Prevent flexbox item from expanding

Tags: css, flexbox

In my sample code, I'm trying to make a toolbar (red), a grid (yellow) and a footer (blue).

I can't make the grid flex to fill the space between the toolbar and the footer, so in my result I can't see the footer.

Here's my sample code:

```js
var data = [];
var colorEditor = null;
var hexEditor = null;
var hexHasKeyPress = false;

$(document).ready(function() {
  var grid = $("#grd")
    .dxDataGrid({
      dataSource: generateData(1000),
      showBorders: true,
      customizeColumns: function(columns) {
        columns[0].width = 70;
      },
      loadPanel: {
        enabled: false,
      },
      scrolling: {
        mode: "infinite",
      },
      sorting: {
        mode: "none",
      },
      height: "100%",
    })
    .dxDataGrid("instance");
});

var s = 123456789;
var random = function() {
  s = (1103515245 * s + 12345) % 2147483647;
  return s % (10 - 1);
};

var generateData = function(count) {
  var i;
  var surnames = ["Smith", "Johnson", "Brown", "Taylor", "Anderson", "Harris", "Clark", "Allen", "Scott", "Carter"];
  var names = ["James", "John", "Robert", "Christopher", "George", "Mary", "Nancy", "Sandra", "Michelle", "Betty"];
  var gender = ["Male", "Female"];
  var items = [],
    startBirthDate = Date.parse("1/1/1975"),
    endBirthDate = Date.parse("1/1/1992");

  for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    var birthDate = new Date(startBirthDate + Math.floor((random() * (endBirthDate - startBirthDate)) / 10));
    birthDate.setHours(12);

    var nameIndex = random();
    var item = {
      id: i + 1,
      firstName: names[nameIndex],
      lastName: surnames[random()],
      gender: gender[Math.floor(nameIndex / 5)],
      birthDate: birthDate,
    };
    items.push(item);
  }
  return items;
};
```

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
  height: 100%;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.toolbar {
  height: 40px;
  min-height: 40px;
  background-color: red;
}

.grid {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: yellow;
  max-height: 100%;
}

.footer {
  height: 40px;
  min-height: 40px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn3.devexpress.com/jslib/20.2.7/js/dx.all.js"></script>
  <link href="https://unpkg.com/devextreme@20.2-next/dist/css/dx.common.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="https://unpkg.com/devextreme@20.2-next/dist/css/dx.light.compact.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="toolbar">123</div>
    <div class="grid">
      <div id="grd" class=""></div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">123</div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Any idea how I can have the red toolbar at top, the blue footer at bottom and then have the yellow grid fill the rest - and the grid must NOT expand.

Comment: Add `min-height: 0` to `.grid`. https://jsfiddle.net/f7xw560y/ ... Explanation in the duplicate.